# Menu button with NoActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have Activity with Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar. My manifest setup: targetSdkVersion=17. Menu button is not showing. How I can show menu button at bottom of my Nexus4?

Comment: Please brief your question more and Try to set your `minSdkVersion=10` in your manifest file and then check.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

set `android:targetSdkVersion="8"`  in manifest.xml ,
Image is taken from Samsung galaxy nexus

**Example**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
It works, but with targetSdkVersion = "8" appears a gradient in the top and bottom of a ScrollView and I don't like it. With targetSdkVersion = "17" no appear gradient, but menu button neither.